# List inside object becomes empty again after exiting function block

Tags: c#, list, iteration, ienumerable

I have an object 'ForValidation' that has List of int as a property, 
and an object 'Validator' which has a Verify(IEnumerable ForValidation) method. Verify method adds numbers in ForValidation list property.

In main function, I have IEnumerable of Validator and IEnumerable of ForValidation

every time Verify(IEnumerable) exits, the list inside ForValidation is back at 0 count.

From my understanding, objects are reference types in C# and modifications from anywhere should reflect in the same object.

I tried running visual studio debugger line by line to check that list inside 'ForValidation' is in fact being added data and then disappears after Verify method.

```
    public class ForValidation
    {
        private readonly object @lock = new object();

        private readonly List<int> ExistenceChecks = new List<int>();

        public IEnumerable<int> ExistsPlaces => ExistenceChecks;

        public string CheckProperty { get; }

        public ForValidation(string checkProperty )
        {
            CheckProperty = checkProperty ;
        }

        public void ConfirmExistence(int place)
        {
            lock (@lock)
            {
                ExistenceChecks.Add(place);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Validator 
    {

        public int ValidatorNumber { get; }

        private readonly Datasource somedatasource;

        public Validator(int number, Datasource someds)
        {
            ValidatorNumber = number;
            somedatasource = someds;
        }

        public void Verify(IEnumerable<ForValidation> forValidations)
        {
            ForValidation[] copy = forValidations.ToArray();

            IEnumerable<string> checkProperties = from member in copy 
                                                  select member.CheckProperty;

            IEnumerable<CompareAgainst> existingMembers 
              = somedatasource.Filter(new CheckPropertiesFilter(checkProperties)).Execute();

            foreach (ForValidation forValidation in copy)
            {
                if (existingMembers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.CheckProperty == forValidation.CheckProperty) != null)
                {
                    forValidation.ConfirmExistence(ValidatorNumber);
                }
            }

            int x = copy.Length;
            //each forValidation.ExistsPlaces has items until this code block
        }
    }
```

```
    main
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<ForValidation> forValidations {...}

        private readonly IEnumerable<Validator> validators {...}

        foreach (Validator validator in validators)
        {
            validator.Verify(forValidations); 
            // each forValidation.ExistsPlaces count is 0 again in this block
        }
    }
```

IExpect every ForValidation items inside forValidations will have remembered items inside its IEnumerable ExistsPlaces property after each Verify method by validators but it becomes 0 count after each iteration of Verify method in the foreach loop

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, you need to post a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. The above is clearly not real code. And besides that simple disqualifying fact, the bigger issue is that when one posts one's impression of the code rather than real code that reproduces the issue, most often the bug is left out of that impression of the code, precisely because the person providing the impression isn't aware of the bug.

Comment: I created a minimal reproducible example and I cannot reproduce the problem :) Please see below.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. Here is my code.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var validators = new[] { new Validator(666), new Validator(667) };
    var forValidations = new [] { new ForValidation("v1"), new ForValidation("v2") };

    Console.WriteLine("Before Verify");
    foreach (var fv in forValidations)
        Console.WriteLine($"Object: {fv.CheckProperty} - count of places: {fv.ExistsPlaces.Count()}");

    foreach (Validator validator in validators)
        validator.Verify(forValidations);

    Console.WriteLine("After Verify");
    foreach (var fv in forValidations)
        Console.WriteLine($"Object: {fv.CheckProperty} - count of places: {fv.ExistsPlaces.Count()}");
}
```

Result

```
Before Verify
Object: v1 - count of places: 0
Object: v2 - count of places: 0
After Verify
Object: v1 - count of places: 2
Object: v2 - count of places: 2
```

Classes:

```
public class ForValidation
{
    private readonly object @lock = new object();

    private readonly List<int> ExistenceChecks = new List<int>();

    public IEnumerable<int> ExistsPlaces => ExistenceChecks;

    public string CheckProperty { get; }

    public ForValidation(string checkProperty)
    {
        CheckProperty = checkProperty;
    }

    public void ConfirmExistence(int place)
    {
        lock (@lock)
        {
            ExistenceChecks.Add(place);
        }
    }
}

public class Validator
{
    public Validator(int validatorNumber)
    {
        ValidatorNumber = validatorNumber;
    }

    public int ValidatorNumber { get; }


    public void Verify(IEnumerable<ForValidation> forValidations)
    {
        ForValidation[] copy = forValidations.ToArray();

        IEnumerable<string> checkProperties = from member in copy
                                              select member.CheckProperty;

        foreach (ForValidation forValidation in copy)
        {
            //if (existingMembers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.CheckProperty == forValidation.CheckProperty) != null)
            {
                forValidation.ConfirmExistence(ValidatorNumber);
            }
        }

        int x = copy.Length;
        //each forValidation.ExistsPlaces has items until this code block
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I changed some variable names when transferring to stackoverflow.

Comment: I'll look again at your code when I'm back at my desk.

Comment: Thanks. I was using Winform with Sql code for datasource... No luck may be I'll deal with it whatever I missed.